# Hyperspectral image storage

Tags: database, image, hadoop, hdfs, storage

I would like to save hyperspectral images using Python, but I don't know where I can persist the data. I have thought about HDFS. I need to do it on my local server without using cloud providers

Is there a way to make it easy, and do you recommend any particular database?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS generally requires you to build and administer your own Hadoop cluster.

I'd consider cloud object storage such as [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) for the following reasons:

1. Relatively cheap
2. Fully managed
3. No restriction on file size or number of files
4. Easy Python APIs
5. Durable - data can be replicated across multiple regions (all handled automatically for you), so you don't need to worry about losing anything if a server dies.

Comment: I need to do it on my local server without using cloud providers. Do you think it would work well with HDFS and MongoDB? Where can I find information about how to store hyperspectral images? I don't see much information about it

Comment: That you can only do it locally would have been useful to know, please can you edit your question to include that? I don't know what a hyperspectral image is but I will assume it's a file. If you have a single-node local server then HDFS is pointless as you're not distributed. RAID HDDs will be your best option locally, but it depends on how many files, how big each file is, how they are read etc

Comment: @Dom You can use MinIO as a local (or clustered) S3 compatible filesystem. HDFS is meant for large (hundreds to millions of MB) individual files. Databases typically have binary blob limits per record. Blob storage is what you want, not block storage

Comment: It would be satellite imagery, but defining a data persistence system, or a particular database

Comment: I have a system with: Jupyter + Spark + Hadoop + ElasticSearch + MariaDB and Superset, and I would like to see if I can add a database where I can save the photos that I am going to download through a spectral camera